# How to get a random function with a truncated normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation, truncated-distributions

My goal is to have a function that given an input value will output a random value that follow a truncated normal distribution,  could you please suggest a function that can do that ? Or guide me a good reference

Comment: What inputs are you referring to? Location, scale and the truncation interval?

Comment: @knrumsey the input is a value say 0.5, I want to generate a random number but with a truncated normal distribution

Comment: @Mohamed, that is not enough information to specify the distribution. I don't even know what $0.5$ means. To generate from a truncated normal, you need to specify the location $\mu$, scale $\sigma$ and truncation interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Besides those listed above, also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179618/how-to-sample-from-a-rectified-gaussian-distribution/